# iframe within iframe is not scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hi there have a page which has an iframe in it.  Now seems that the only way I can get Google map or Blogger on to the site is in another iframe within the main i frame.

Now I have this script which was working to stop the scrolling in the main iframe, iframe_a but how do I get the i frame with Google map and Blogger to not scroll?
I have included that script again within the page which has Blogger and the one which has Google maps on it which gets put in the main i frame_a
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

javascript:
HTML5
CSS3

```
<script>

  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>


    <iframe name="iframe_a" src="home.html"  id="iframe_a" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />

            <p>Your browser does not support i frames.</p>
</iframe>


    iframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width: 735px;
    height: 0;
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that blogger's iframe is within home.html. I suggest adding the following css to that iframe if you want to remove the scrolling. Note that whatever extends past that iframe would be lost forever.

```
iframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Might I strongly suggest not using two nested iframes? I don't know your exact situation, but this makes things cumbersome.

Comment: Yeah I didn't want to use the iframe with the Google map and blogger but when I type the short url in to the address bar of the browser I go to those pages but when I a href and target to the main iframe which is on other pages it  doesn't work only seems to work with their iframe link from the website.  I'll try adding that css thanks.